# retrieving data from single column of multiple tables to act as a column for another table

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have a table stock which have columns stockID as primary key, Stock_Description(displaying stockA,StockB,StockC).

Then I have tables stock A, StockB and StockC all of them having column Revision, Id as primary key and StockId as Secondary key.

I want to display a column in table stock that shows the corresponding revision for each Stock_Description and also Column type that display A,B,C. Database is mysql.

Comment: Could you please clean a bit the post, to be able to understand better what you need... also what have you tried?

Comment: You want to insert all the data from those three tables where? or it's just a selection of data?

Comment: It's not clear what you want, What do you mean by Column Type?, if you could make an example of what you need we could help

Comment: @JonathanS. I have three tables StockA, StockB, StockC all have PK on there respective ID's i.e A_ID, B_ID, C_ID and SK on Stock ID. I have another table Stock that has collection of all the stock A,B and C ,,and Has a PK on StockID and Description. Now I want to select a column in such a way that it gives me stock type i.e type=Stock A, Stock b or Stock C..

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
/*
  Design
  <stock_description> {<stock_id>, <stock_a>, <stock_b>, <stock_c>}
  <stock_*> {<Id>, <stock_id>, <revision>}
*/

SELECT
    sd.`<stock_id>` 'Stock ID',
    sd.`<stock_a>` 'Stock A', sa.`<revision>` 'Stock A Revision',
    sd.`<stock_b>` 'Stock B', sb.`<revision>` 'Stock B Revision',
    sd.`<stock_c>` 'Stock C', sc.`<revision>` 'Stock C Revision'
FROM
    `<stock_description>` sd
    INNER JOIN `<stock_a>` sa ON sa.`<stock_id>` = sd.`<stock_id>`
    INNER JOIN `<stock_b>` sb ON sb.`<stock_id>` = sd.`<stock_id>`
    INNER JOIN `<stock_c>` sc ON sc.`<stock_id>` = sd.`<stock_id>`
GROUP BY
    sd.`<stock_id>`;
```

Favor, just replace the `<enclosed>` parts with the corresponding table name or column name in your database. Cheers!